# jquery dialog - replacing dialog element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I have a document with a #page div, which contains a jQuery dialog div #dia and the JS to create it. Something like this:

```
<script>
var x;
</script>
<div id="page">
    <div id="dia">bla</div>
    <script>
    $(function () { x = $('#dia').dialog(); });
    </script>
</div>
```

This works fine so far. However, now I need to remove the contents of #page and replace them with new content. This new content will contain another div with id #dia and the same JS code to make that one into a dialog as well.

This does not seem to work. Instead, it seems like x is still the old dialog from before the replacement.

What I think happens is that jQuery moves the #dia div somewhere else when I create the dialog and thus when I replace the contents of #page the old dialog is still there. Then, when my $('#dia').dialog() code runs it is just applied to the old div, which is already a dialog.

I have tried running $('#page').empty(), x.dialog('destroy') and x.remove() before replacing the elements but none of this seems to help.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: The variable x is assigned to the global window-object, right? so it is definitely still exist when the content is removed or deleted.

Comment: Yes, it still exists. However it should get overwritten once the new <script> tag is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is set to only run on document ready.

```
$(function() { ... });
```

is a short hand for

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

Because you are dynamically loading the content into the page, but not actually changing the page, it will not fire a new document ready event. Subsequently, the value of x will not get changed, and the new content will not get converted to a dialog.

If you are going to dynamically load in the content, without reloading the page, you need to use a callback function to re-trigger the dialog initialize.

```
<script>
    var x;

    function reloadContent(url) {
        $("#page").load(url, function () {
           x = $("#dia").dialog();
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="page">
    <div id="dia">bla</div>
    <script>
        $(function () { x = $('#dia').dialog(); });
    </script>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="reloadContent('new/url/for/content');>Change Content</button>
```

If you are going to manually swap out the content by using `$.html()`, then you will also have to manually reinitialize the dialog box as well.

Comment: I thought so as well initially but apparently this is not the problem. The code definitely gets executed, it just doesn't turn the right div into a dialog.

Comment: @Nils What are you expecting to get from x? Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uE2F8/), that is properly swapping the dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for this! After seeing it work properly in your fiddle I started searching for what made my script different from yours and found a bug causing my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-run the selector via a callback after loading new content. Something like so:

```
$("div#page").load("/your/url/", function() {
    x = $('#dia').dialog();
});
```

Otherwise, the pointer will still be pointing back at the obsolete element.

Alternatively, you could go more generic and do something like this in order to reload the variable every time #page is replaced:

```
var x;
function initDialog(){
    x = $('#dia').dialog();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#page").ajaxSuccess(initDialog);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not using the .load() method but replacing the content manually via html(), so I don't think this applies.

Comment: Then you could simply encapsulate your dialog functionality into a function as I did above, and re-call that function after you replace the html.